# Class 'Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegServiceProvider\FFMpeg' not found

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

### Encountered error

> Class 'Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegServiceProvider\FFMpeg' not found

I'm building a web application to upload a video and store it in cloud. I want to get the duration of the uploaded video. I tried to install `laravel/FFMpeg` package. After doing all the steps, I'm getting the above error.

### Code

My controller code:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Providers\DropboxServiceProvider;
use Dropbox\Client;
use Dropbox\WriteMode;
use Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegServiceProvider as FFMpeg; 
//use Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegFacade as FFMpeg;
//use FFMpeg;

class FileController extends Controller 
{
   public function FileUpload(Request $request)
   {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $note = $request->input('note');
    //$request->file('file')->store('assets');
    if($file)
    { 

         //Storage::disk('local')->put($file, $file);
        //$file = $request->input('file')->store('1.png');
         $file1 = Storage::disk('local')->put('' ,$request->file) ;
         $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

         Storage::move(''.$file1, $filename); // keep the same folder to just rename 



         $file = FFMPEG\FFMpeg::open($filename);
         $durationInSeconds = $file->getDurationInSeconds();
         return view('users/order-status')->with('file',$durationInSeconds);
    }
    else
    {
        $file ="not found";
    }
    return view('users/order-status')->with('file',$file);
   }

   public function dropboxFileUpload(Request $request)
    {


        $file = $request->input('file');
        //Storage::disk('dropbox')->put('file.txt', 'Hello laravel ');
        //$path = $request->input('file')->store('audio');
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file, 'Contents');
        echo asset('storage/"$file"');
        //$file = "/storage/app/".$file. "";

        //dd($path);
        //$file = dd($path);
    return view('users/order-status')->with('file',$file);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I added highlighting to your question so that the other readers can easily identify the problem. Also using headings to split the parts of your question - beginning with the error you receive, a short summary of what you want to achieve (if required to understand the question) and your code - to increase readability. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the facade to your app.php. Follow below link if not.

[Packagist Link](https://packagist.org/packages/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg)

After that, run composer dump-autoload once.

Then you can change your line of code from

```
$file = FFMPEG\FFMpeg::open($filename);
```

to

```
$file = FFMpeg::open($filename);
```

Let me know if its working or not..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time . I have added all the above steps which is given in FFMPEG . And added the facade in app.php too . Still getting the error.